# How to get a JSON from an URL

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have this code:

```js
function getJSON(url) {
    var resp ;
    var xmlHttp ;

    resp  = '' ;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(xmlHttp != null)
    {
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }

    return resp ;
}

var data ;
data = getJSON('https://gpsfront.aliexpress.com/getRecommendingResults.do?offset=1&postback=8fa025df-0612-4a7f-9901-5820a67473e1&widgetId=7237617') ;

alert(data);
alert("");
```

When I get the JSON using an [URL like this](https://soundcloud.com/oembedformat=json&height=300&url=https://soundcloud.com/giorgiomartini), then everything works and the JSON is displayed in the alert. However, when the [URL is this](https://gpsfront.aliexpress.com/getRecommendingResults.do?offset=1&postback=8fa025df-0612-4a7f-9901-5820a67473e1&widgetId=7237617), then the script does not work. The JSON is given in asynchronous code and it's valid, so what can be the reason?

I  have another question. How can I scrape the HTML of a page and place it in a variable using pure javascript?

Comment: Since you consider software none productive way to get it, you can try pen and paper or just type it manually, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should consider using the [fetch interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and the [async/await keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

You could write it like this. As for your links, I'm getting a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem. Are you sure you are using the right API?

```js
const getJson = async(p_url)=>{
    const params = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };
    const req = await fetch(
        p_url,
        params
    );
    if(req.ok){
        const rep =await req.json();
        return rep;
    }
}
```

as for getting the whole HTML of a page you simply have to use the DOM

```js
const page = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
console.log(page);
```